# Touch screen won't work properly after sleep - Ubuntu 16.04 with Lenovo yoga 2 (not pro)

Tags: suspend, lenovo, touchscreen

It's a problem that is common on the Lenovo yoga 2 on windows. I found a solution (still on windows) that was to restart a driver manually after sleep.

I switched to Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago, but I can't find a solution, since I don't have a lot of experience on Ubuntu.

Did anyone experience the same issue ?

Thank you

Comment: To debug issues occurring during suspension or after wake-up, please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo dmesg` and the content of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` after a (potentially unsuccessful) suspend/wake-up cycle. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I can't join the output of `sudo dmesg` on the forum, it's too long, how should I do ? About `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, I don't have that file appearing

Comment: You can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question.

Comment: So here's the link of my pastie : http://paste.ubuntu.com/23061266/
On windows, I had to restart this after sleep : USB\\VID_04F3&PID_0303' ; in case it helps
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your link works but its formatting is broken. Also, please [edit] your question when you want to add information.